# htaccess language redirect and language selector

Tags: .htaccess, web, internationalization

im trying to create a code for redirect users to the language of their browsers. The problem is that the website has language selector too. And this redirection code force language not allowing the user select the language he want to select. 
The languages urls are :

```
http://www.example.com (English)
http://www.example.com/es (spanish)
http://www.example.com/fr (french)
```

There is one folder for each language, so, spanish is in a folder called "es" and inside of the folder is one index.html, this file points asset files from parent directory.

This is the code inside the .htaccess archive.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|php)$

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(es.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/es/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /es/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(fr.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/fr/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fr/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

And the code for change the language manually:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/es">es </a> <a href="http://www.example.com/fr"> fr</a>
```

Comment: How is user selected language being passed to server? In a query string?

Comment: No, the site have one folder for each language. The user clicks in a html link.

Comment: OK provide sample of links for each language?

Comment: its a a href type link

Comment: If link is already pointing to `/es/some-file` then rewrite rule won't fire and you're good. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the rewrite rule fires. everytime. The htaccess is in base directory, with css, js folders, and the languages have their own index file. When im trying click to change language, the rewrite rule fires.

Comment: You have this condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/es/.*) [NC]` which will stop firing this rule if URL already has `/es/` at the start.

Comment: ok, so the problem is the site urls are www.example.com/es and should be es.example.com  ? Now the url has /es/ at the end.

Comment: In that case I have to say that you haven't descried the problem clearly and completely. If you edit your question and put up all the details then you might get some answers here.

Comment: Sorry, the question is edited now. Thank you very much for your help.